# The same PD code seems to yield two different knot diagrams of the Hopf link

Tags: knot-theory

The PD code $[(2, 3, 1, 4), (4, 1, 3, 2)]$ seems to map to a non-unique knot diagram. I can describe the following two Hopf links

[image]

with different orientations with this same PD code. As I understand it, while a link diagram does not have a unique PD code, a given PD code should map to just one knot diagram. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hopf links have an orientation ambiguity when using the increasing-index orientation convention for unoriented PD codes. A sure way to avoid this ambiguity is to switch to oriented PD codes, where you could write

```
PD[Xm[2,3,1,4], Xm[4,1,3,2]]
```

to unambiguously mean the first diagram in your linked image. There are details in the KnotTheory package's documentation: http://katlas.org/wiki/Planar_Diagrams

Another option is to have degree-2 nodes to disambiguate the orientation. For example,

```
[(3,4,1,5), (5,1,6,2), (2,3), (6,4)]
```

Now there are at least three indices in each component.

This ambiguity also arises when a link is an obvious connect sum with a Hopf link. It's a known problem that Scott Morrison, one of the authors of KnotTheory, once warned me about.

[image: Positive and negative crossing types]

---

For illustration, here are the four ways of interpreting orientations for the PD code `[(2,3,1,4), (4,1,3,2)]`:

[image: Four possible interpretations of the original PD code]

Comment: I may be missing something, but no matter how I look at it, with this notation it seems the first diagram would be PD[Xm[2, 3, 1, 4], Xm[4, 1, 3, 2]] (as would be the second)? Wouldn't Xp[4, 1, 3, 2] in the first diagram mean the second link is CW rather than CCW?

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan No, you're right, it should be two Xm nodes. When there was one Xp node the orientations didn't match up correctly, which is an error.

Comment: In that case, does the introduction of the different crossing types actually solve the ambiguity? And do you happen to know of any codings with no ambiguities? It seems like DT and Gauss codes also have their own ambiguities, and the degree 2-nodes didn't seem to solve the problem based on [these diagrams](https://imgur.com/uYJDyZi)

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan I assumed your two diagrams were actually different but they're the same -- remember that knot diagrams are on $S^2$, so you can slide arcs "past infinity." The original PD code is still ambiguous since you can actually change the orientation of either component. The other Hopf link is `PD[Xp[3,2,4,1], Xp[2,3,1,4]]`. Yes, the oriented codes are unambiguous, up to isotopy of the diagram on $S^2$, assuming the diagram is connected.

Comment: The diagrams you linked are also both the same. If you want a PD code to be unambiguous in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you have to make up a convention for what will be the outer face of the diagram -- for example, "the outer face will be to the right of arc 1".

Comment: You're right, all of these diagrams actually represent the same link. However, I've rechecked millions of times (including with a friend) and it seems to me that **both** diagrams can be represented with the code `PD[Xm[2, 3, 1, 4], Xm[4, 1, 3, 2]]`, so the introduction of crossing types doesn't seem to solve the diagrammatic ambiguity. However, maybe it is the case that while PD code has ambiguities for which diagram it generates, in the case of ambiguities all the different diagrams actually represent the same link?

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan I'm saying something stronger than that the two diagrams represent the same link -- *they're the same diagram*. You have to remember they're on $S^2$, and there's no ambiguity there. The 2D pictures you're drawing are stereographic projections from the 2-sphere, and what I mentioned about the "outer face" is about which point you're choosing for the stereographic projection.

Comment: Ah, okay, I do see what you mean. Thank you very much for all your help in this. One (hopefully last) question - you mentioned that there is ambiguity "when a link is an obvious connect sum with a Hopf link". In this case, are the "ambiguous" diagrams truly different? (Perhaps this is a better question to ask the authors of KnotTheory themselves, I can always try to do that as well)

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan Hint: in the `[(2,3,1,4),(4,1,3,2)]` code, how did you choose the orientations of the components? Is there really a way to choose one of the four options as being *the* orientation? (Hint 2: this is what the Xp/Xm thing is solving.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I'm following your hints. As I understand it, all four of these [diagrams](https://imgur.com/3EBnZlp) (which are actually the same diagram) are described by `PD[Xm[2, 3, 1, 4], Xm[4, 1, 3, 2]]`. I think all of these crossings are left-handed. So at least in this case, there doesn't seem to be a way to choose an orientation as _the_ orientation?

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan I added an illustration. All four of these should have a different Xm/Xp code.

Comment: Wouldn't the PD code for the top-left diagram be `[(2, 3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1)]`, for bottom-left be `[(1, 4, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2)]` , and for bottom-right be `[(3, 2, 4, 1), (1, 4, 2, 3)]`? Following the convention of listing the incoming understrand as first in the tuple for each crossing, and then going CCW around the crossing (as described in the same [Wikipedia page](http://katlas.org/wiki/Planar_Diagrams) you linked). I see that the top-right and bottom-left diagrams have `Xp` rather than `Xm` crossings, but their PD code doesn't seem to match the originals anyway?

Comment: @SophiaTevosyan Huh, I never knew that convention the orientation of PD codes, sorry for any confusion! I had always understood a PD code to allow `(a, b, c, d) <-> (c, d, a, b)`, since you can recover the orientation from the fact the indices are sequential (so long as each component has at least three indices!). I asked Scott yesterday, and he mentioned how even with this convention, if you're looking at a single crossing you can't reliably determine the orientation of the overstrand when there are Hopf connect summands. The `Xp` and `Xm` versions are perfectly unambiguous.

Comment: For what it's worth, the KnotTheory source code gets the orientation of a crossing by looking at which way the indices increment -- I believe this is where I got my understanding of PD codes. It's good to know about this, thanks for pointing it out, and I'd better make sure [https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/](KnotFolio) outputs the correct PD code given the orientation...

Comment: I think I see what you mean. It seems like for a crossing `[i, j, k, l]`, KnotTheory looks at the relative difference between j and l to determine the type of crossing. And if I understand you correctly, this strategy fails for Hopf connect summands, so in this case we have to use `Xp`/`Xm` to denote the crossing type. This doesn't disambiguate my [example from before](https://imgur.com/3EBnZlp), but this doesn't actually matter since these are all the same diagram on $S^2$ anyway. But for truly distinct diagrams, introducing `Xp`/`Xm` leads to an unambiguous map from PD code to link diagram?